# Problem with consumable in app purchases

Tags: iphone, objective-c, store

I have problem with consumable in app purchases on sandbox. When I try to buy consumable product more then once I get "You've already purchased this but it hasn't been downloaded" error info. I have tried this on many test accounts and this problem is sill there. Im sure I finish all transactions with

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```

Have you found any workaround? How can I be sure my code will work in real App Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue, create a new test account and it should work

Comment: Well, looks like i had something messed up with pending/not finished transactions on my test device. It works after hard reset, creating new test accounts and new in app purchases ids.